# Movie where aliens save humans from asteroids and then build them a second Earth

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I just remember like alien spaceships hovering over Earth and everyone was scared they were going to attack, but in the end the aliens were there to protect the humans from an asteroid attack and then the aliens built the humans a second Earth to live on.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made?

Answer (score 4):

You're probably thinking of ***[The Beyond](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5723416/)*** (2017).

> Set in 2019, The Beyond chronicles the groundbreaking mission which sent astronauts – modified with advanced robotics, through a newly discovered wormhole known as the Void. When the mission returns unexpectedly, the space agency races to discover what the astronauts encountered on their first of its kind interstellar space journey.

The plot involves the Earth being surrounded mysterious black spheres, which humans interpret as a prelude to an alien attack. However, it later transpires that aliens placed the spheres there to protect the Earth from debris that would be approaching it from a wormhole.

Within the last ten minutes of the film, it's also revealed that the aliens created a second Earth-like planet within the solar system, which humans refer to as 'Earth 2.'